# how to load sample.RData file using R?

Tags: r

I am trying to load "sample.RData" file in R. The error it gives is

> Error in load("sample.RData") :    bad restore file magic number (file
> may be corrupted) -- no data loaded In addition: Warning message: file
> ‘sample.RData’ has magic number 'RDX3'   Use of save versions prior to
> 2 is deprecated

I checked many solutions like, to use save() instead of load etc. but not successful. Please recommend any solution.

Comment: If you are using an .Rdata file made with an earlier (or later) version of R, you may be out of luck. The R Core says "don't". there is no assurance that the format of .Rdata files will stay the same from version to version.

Comment: How was this `sample.RData` file created? What version of R are you running?

Comment: I dont know because somebody else has given this file for solving an exercise. But some of the students have already performed the test, which shows that there is no problem in the file.

Comment: So what version of R are you running?

Comment: I have upgraded the version to 4.1.1 and now it worked. Probably the file was created through a newer version and mine was an older one, therefore after I upgraded, it worked. thanks a lot.